# MongoDB indexes are ignored inside the $facet pipeline

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have all combination of compound indexes for this collection. The aggregattion query i used is:

```
db.products.aggregate( [
    {
      $facet: {
        "categorizedByColor": [
          { 
            $match: { 
              size: { $in : [50,60,70] },
              brand: { $in : ["Raymond","Allen Solly","Van Heusen"] } 
            } 
          },
          {
            $bucket: {
              groupBy: "$color",
              default: "Other",
              output: {
                "count": { $sum: 1 }
              }
            }
          }
        ],
        "categorizedBySize": [
          { 
            $match: { 
              color: { $in : ["Red","Green","Blue"] },
              brand: { $in : ["Raymond","Allen Solly","Van Heusen"] } 
            } 
          },
          {
            $bucket: {
              groupBy: "$size",
              default: "Other",
              output: {
                "count": { $sum: 1 }
              }
            }
          }
        ],
        "categorizedByBrand": [
          { 
            $match: { 
              color: { $in : ["Red","Green","Blue"] },
              size: { $in : [50,60,70] }
            } 
          },
          {
            $bucket: {
              groupBy: "$brand",
              default: "Other",
              output: {
                "count": { $sum: 1 }
              }
            }
          }
        ],
        "productResults": [
          { 
            $match: {
              color: { $in : ["Red","Green","Blue"] },
              size: { $in : [50,60,70] },
              brand: { $in : ["Raymond","Allen Solly","Van Heusen"] }
            } 
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  ]);
```

This query took around 6s to populate the results. Is there any alterative approach available to use mongodb indexing?

**Note:** This aggregation query have more than 14 facet pipelines. For better understanding i have provided only 4 facet pipelines.

Comment: facet cannot use index, so if possible try to use the index before the facet(a match with $or for example), another alternative can be to send more queries that can use the index. facet runs 1 pipeline after another here like 14 pipelines.

Comment: You can add `OR` condition as a first stage with all colors, size, brands. By this way, you will have all the docs required for the following stages. Then you could apply facets as you already have. By this way, your first `match or` stage could use index

Comment: If you don't do anything with the facets on the later stages, don't use them at all. Run 14 queries and benefit from indexes on each one. Don't try to put whole application logic in a single request, leave this approach to SQL, it's optimised for it. Mongo is much better in handling high volume of simple queries. It keeps a pool of open connections from each client exactly for this purpose.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes 14 queries can do the job and sometimes not.
If the `$facet` is the first step in the aggregation pipeline, 14 queries are a more efficient option, but if this `$facet` is following a complex pipeline to create or filter these documents, there are alternatives to this `$facet`'s `$match`. Sometimes One needs a snapshot of the db, which 14 queries can not give, since the db may change in-between.

Since we don't have any data of former actions in this pipeline, and the question is regarding alternatives that will allow to use the indexes to make the rest of the query faster, I can offer one option for example. It is hard to tell if it will be faster than other options, according to the data we have here, but it will allow to use the indexes, which is the main idea of the question:

1. The first step is according to both @Takis and @Gibbs smart suggestion.
2. The second phase will use the indexes to make the `$facet`'s `$match` much easier, by marking in advance which document belongs to which `$facet` pipeline.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
{ 
    $match: {$or: [
        {size:  {$in: [50, 60, 70]}},
        {color: {$in: ["Red", "Green", "Blue"]}},
        {brand: {$in: ["Raymond", "Allen Solly", "Van Heusen"]}}
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    $addFields: {
      categorizedByColor: {
        $cond: [{$and: [{$in: ["$size",[50, 60, 70]]},
                        {$in: ["$brand",["Raymond", "Allen Solly", "Van Heusen"]]}]
          }, true, false]
      },
      categorizedBySize: {
        $cond: [{$and: [{$in: [ "$color", ["Red", "Green", "Blue"]]},
              {$in: ["$brand",["Raymond", "Allen Solly", "Van Heusen"]]}]
          }, true, false]
      },
      categorizedByBrand: {
         $cond: [{$and: [{$in: [ "$color", ["Red", "Green", "Blue"]]},
                        {$in: ["$size",[50, 60, 70]]}]
          }, true, false]
      },
      productResults: {
        $and: [{$in: ["$color", ["Red", "Green", "Blue"]]},
                {$in: ["$size",[50, 60, 70]]},
                {$in: ["$brand",["Raymond", "Allen Solly", "Van Heusen"]]}]
          }
      }
  },
  {
    $facet: {
      "categorizedByColor": [
        {$match: {categorizedByColor: true}},
        {
          $bucket: {
            groupBy: "$color",
            default: "Other",
            output: {"count": {$sum: 1}}
          }
        }
      ],
      "categorizedBySize": [
        {$match: {categorizedBySize: true}},
        {
          $bucket: {
            groupBy: "$size",
            default: "Other",
            output: {"count": {$sum: 1}}
          }
        }
      ],
      "categorizedByBrand": [
        {$match: {categorizedByBrand: true}},
        {
          $bucket: {
            groupBy: "$brand",
            default: "Other",
            output: {"count": {$sum: 1}}
          }
        }
      ],
      "productResults": [{$match: {productResults: true}}]
    }
  }
])
```

[Playground example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/dT58TCzifVT)

Going a step further, there is even a way to get these results in one query without the `$facet` step at all, by using `$group` with `$push` with `$cond` instead. This should iterate over the documents once, instead of 14 times, but may result in a large document (with duplicates of data per each categorization). The main idea of such a solution can be seen on [this mongoDB playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/4znsB3A5AU6). It is important to say that these methods are not necessarily better or worse than other. The "right" solution depends on your specific case and data, which we can't see here. You asked for alternative approaches which will allow to use the indexes, so I'm pointing some directions.

Comment: Is this answering your question?

Answer (score 0):

[image: Facet and indexes]

Facet stage by default cannot use indexes and will perform COLLSCAN (full scan) when executed.

Because of that, you should use filtering (and sorting) way earlier in your pipeline, in order to get the "common data" for all the sub-pipelines in $facet.
So, in your case, filters :

```
        $match: {
          color: { $in : ["Red","Green","Blue"] },
          size: { $in : [50,60,70] },
          brand: { $in : ["Raymond","Allen Solly","Van Heusen"] }
        }
```

should be used as a first stage in pipeline, then followed by $facet.

Hope I was clear enough. :)

Comment: There is no common match criteria to use it in earlier stage, if you look deeply you may get to know each facet has different $match criteria.